How to get the unicode of a character in Python?
Wanna get the unicode of chinese or vietnamese's han-nom and japanese characters
I've tried these code
text = "";

br = text.encode("unicode-escape");

print(br);

and got
b'\\U0002c5b0'

But what should I do when I want to have something like U+2C5B0 or U2C5B0 ?

FYI: "The Unicode of a character" doesn't really make much sense. Unicode is a whole big standard with many different parts to it. You want the Unicode code point.

Yea ... in "Unicode of a character", "Unicode" could also mean the UTF-8 encoding, UTF-16 encoding and so on.  And even "of a character" is ambiguous in many contexts.  (Character in what character set?)  I recommend you do some background reading on Unicode so that you know and understand the correct terminology ... and then >use< it.

You can use the ord function to get the character's numeric code point and format it with the 04X specifier in an f-string to display the code point as uppercased hexadecimals that are 0-padded up to 4 characters wide:
print(f'U+{ord(text):04X}')

Demo here

print(f'U+{ord(text):04X}') may be a better version,  conforming to conventions used to display codepoints.
